# Virtual keyboard in Safari causes black space under app body and scrolling outside of it

Tags: css, reactjs, iphone, safari

I'm creating a chatbot app in React. It works fine on other browsers but on Safari whenever the virtual keyboard is open it causes the entire body to become draggable, the scrollbar extends way below the body and a black space appears below the body and above the keyboard.

This is the screenshot:

[image: Open virtual keyboard on Safari causing the issue]

This is how my App.css looks like:

```
body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I've tried setting

```
height: 100vh;
min-height: 100vh;
```

on both `html` and `body` tags but it didn't do anything. If I put `overflow: hidden` on `body` it messes up the inner container scrollbar, as it does if I use `position: fixed` on `body` as I've seen recommended somewhere. Is there a pure CSS solution for this or am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I got the exact same problem. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have decided to put it aside for now.

Comment: Has anyone solved this issue?? It looks like it happens on any page with an input. The bug is directly related to the iOS Safari Keyboard. It is most noticeable if the input is on the very bottom of the page and if the input has to do with a chat conversation experience.